# Containernet: docker logs command doesn't return anything

Tags: docker, containers, sdn

When I run containers with [containernet](https://github.com/containernet/containernet) command "docker logs" doesn't return anything.

I have verified it several times with different containers, for example with tomcat image. When I run the same containers without containernet I can see logs with "docker logs".

Has anyone managed to show docker logs while running containers on containernet or has an idea what could be the reason?